# What is the regular expression of the language accepted by the following NFA?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-expressions

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyy3m5m5bvhj1rt/NFA1.jpg?dl=0
This is the NFA.

RE = (aa + ab) a* ((ba+bb) a*) *
This is the solution i came up with but i'm looking for an optimal solution.

Comment: Optimal in what sense?

Comment: Something more compact,a more simplified version.

Comment: I can shorten it a bit and have done so in my answer; I doubt that one can do much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know whether it’s optimal in any reasonable sense, but $a(a+b)(a+ba+bb)^*$ works and is a bit more compact.

Comment: If there’s a genuine problem with the answer, I’d appreciate being informed, so that I can correct or withdraw it; otherwise the downvote is mere vandalism.

Comment: Ah now that's more like it! After some minutes of tinkering with my previous solution, I came up with a similar solution : aa + ab (a + (ba + bb))* .